# Magento 2.2 : How to programatically clear the varnish cache by cache tag

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, cache, varnish

I need to switch the currency based on user IP location so I'm using this auto currency [extension](https://github.com/chapagain/auto-currency-switcher-2), it works only when I disabled the FPC otherwise it just cache the previous content and never gets changed.

I'm looking to programmatically clear the varnish cache by the cache tag of the store currency. I tried the below logic in the observer (**controller_action_predispatch**) but it does not work.

```
protected $config;
protected $purgeCache;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\PageCache\Model\Config $config,
    \Magento\CacheInvalidate\Model\PurgeCache $purgeCache
) {
    $this->config = $config;
    $this->purgeCache = $purgeCache;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $tags = [];
    $pattern = "((^|,)%s(,|$))";
    $tags[] = sprintf($pattern, 'store');
    $this->purgeCache->sendPurgeRequest(implode('|', array_unique($tags)));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to invalidate cache via Magento which is under the 2 difficult things in CS:

1. Naming things
2. Cache invalidation
3. Off-by one errors :)

Instead leverage Varnish itself with a module which implements the same maxmind GeoIP db within Varnish to set proper HTTP Headers like so:

`set req.http.X-Country-Code = geoip.country_code(req.http.X-Forwarded-For);`

Full Varnish config example in original sources.

**NOTE**: Your host setup may need adjusting, and Varnish will need to be recompiled which can be a task in itself with versions specific for the module and Magento.

Source:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/217313/69
- https://rageagainstshell.com/2016/05/geoip-location-in-varnish/

Comment: superb idea! I'll try this and let you know the results

Comment: I import the geoip vmod in varnish and successfully get the country code of the user and set in the header request. I read the request header in Magento and used it. This method also faces the same issue. When I first load the site in France server it returns the country code as FR, after that I load the site in India, it returns again FR when I refresh the cache that time only it returns IN for India.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/23528/69 since Magento uses cookies for currency you'll need some vcl re-tooling most likely.

Comment: still, I'm not successful. If you have detailed working answer, please share with me. I'm using M2.2.2 EE version.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to implement a feature that needs to bypass the FPC in Magento 2, the recommended way is to write a Punch Hole implementation for your requirement.

Magento 2 has a structured way to get this written: I have an example at:
https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/punchhole